SqlCommand doesn't return result from the C# application (MS Access database)
I am trying to connect to a MS Access database from C# webforms.
I did this:
var parameters = new KeyValuePair<string, object>[]
             {
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@ProjectId", currentInfo.ProjectId),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@core", Convert.ToInt16(catalogue.Core.ToString())),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@sizee", catalogue.Size)),
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>("@applicationId", Convert.ToInt32(applicationComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()))
             };
DataTable typesTable = helper.GetRowsByQuery("FillType",parameters, currentInfo.DBPath);

This is the method of connecting to the database:
public DataTable GetRowsByQuery(string queryOrTable, KeyValuePair<string, object>[] parameters, string dbPath)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(GetStringConnection(dbPath));

    string sqlCommand = GetSqlCommand(queryOrTable);

    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCommand, connection);

    if (parameters != null)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> o in parameters)
        {
            var parameter = new OleDbParameter(o.Key, o.Value);
            SetOleDbTypeAndSize(parameter, o.Value);
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);                
        }
    }

    command.CommandText = sqlCommand;

    adapter.SelectCommand = command;

    try
    {
        connection.Open();

        if (table == null)
        {
            table = new DataTable();
            table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            adapter.FillSchema(table, SchemaType.Source);
        }

        adapter.Fill(table);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return table;
}

The query command is something like this
SELECT DISTINCT Catalogue.Type  
FROM (CableProperty  
INNER JOIN Catalogue ON CableProperty.CatalogueId = Catalogue.Id)    
WHERE (Catalogue.Core = @core) 
  AND (Catalogue.[Size] = '@sizee') 
  AND (CableProperty.ProjectId = @projectId) 
  AND (CableProperty.CableApplicationId = @applicationId) 
               

The query returns result on the MS Access database itself directly, but doesn't return any results in my C# application....
If I remove the inner join condition on Catalogue:
(Catalogue.Core = @core) AND (Catalogue.[Size] = '@sizee')

it returns result in the application also.

You may consider referring to the documentation for OleDb where you'll find OleDb.Parameter (see the Remarks). You may also consider looking at the using statement.

For debugging, add the following: to your code 'foreach ( OleDbParameter p In command.Parameters) {  Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName + ": " + p.Value.ToString()); }. You may try using ! instead of @ for your parameter names which should make them output properly in Debug.WriteLine statement (even though OleDb doesn't use named parameters).

Don't add quotes around string parameters. The equivalent raw sql to compare against would be something like declare @sizee varchar .... select @sizee = 'something' ... AND (Catalogue.[Size] = @sizee)

As noted in the comments, you don't surround parameters with quotes.
And, really no need to try and create your own list (keypair) of parameters, since the ADO.NET SQL command object already has such a pre built collection for you.
Keep in mind, when using the MS Access data engine, the order of parameters matters, and MUST match the order they appear in the query.
So, this:
        string sSQL =
            @"SELECT DISTINCT Catalogue.Type  
            FROM (CableProperty  
            INNER JOIN Catalogue ON CableProperty.CatalogueId = Catalogue.Id)    
            WHERE (Catalogue.Core = @core) 
              AND (Catalogue.[Size] = @sizee) 
              AND (CableProperty.ProjectId = @projectId) 
              AND (CableProperty.CableApplicationId = @applicationId)";


        OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(sSQL);
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@core", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 123;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@sizee", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = "big";
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@projectId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 789;
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@applicationId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 5555;

        DataTable CatItems = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);

So, for an easy to use "general" routine that you can use throughout your application?
I suggest this public static routine:
    public static DataTable MyRstP(OleDbCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(GetConStr()))
        {
            using (cmd)
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    rstData.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }       

Note that you can even use "?" for the parameters in the SQL, since as I noted, in the case of Access, the parameter name actually does not matter, but only the order in which the parameters are added.
So, I see little value in attempting to create your own keypair, since as noted the ADO.NET SQL command object already has such a built-in collection, and more important, you can use the OleDbType to strong cast (automatic) the input parameter type for you.
Also note how the routine wraps the connection object in a using statement, and this is also highly recommended to correctly dispose of the connection to the database.

MS Access does not support named parameters, you should use question marks (?) A placeholder. For example:
foreach (var param in parameters) 
{ 
  OleDbParameter oleDbParameter = new OleDbParameter("?", param.Value);
  SetOleDbTypeAndSize(oleDbParameter, param.Value);
  command.Parameters.Add(oleDbParameter);
}

